# jQuery timer not working properly

Tags: jquery

```
//Content Slider

$("#example p:first").css("display", "block");
jQuery.fn.timer = function () {
    var posx = $(".SlideMask").css('-moz-transform').split(/[()]/)[1];
    //var posx = $(".SlideMask").css('-webkit-transform').split(/[()]/)[1];

    var currentTranslate = (posx.split(',')[4]);
    var now = currentTranslate - 1000;

    if (now < -1999)  now = 0;

    $(".SlideMask").animate({ SlideNext: now }, {
        step: function (val, fx) {
            $(".SlideMask").css('-webkit-transform', "translateX(" + val + "px)");
            $(".SlideMask").css('-moz-transform', "translateX(" + val + "px)");
        },
        duration: 'slow'
    }, 'easeInElastic');
};

window.setInterval(function () {
    $("#example").timer();
}, 7000);




//Tech Slider

$("#TechSlider").css("display", "block");
jQuery.fn.timer = function() {
    var posY = $(".imgContentSlideMask").css('-moz-transform').split(/[()]/)[1];
    //var posx = $(".SlideMask").css('-webkit-transform').split(/[()]/)[1];

    var currentTranslate = (posY.split(',')[5]);
    var now = currentTranslate - 230;

    if (now < -460) now = 0;
    if (now == 0) $       ("#bullet1").attr('checked', 'checked');
   else if (now == -230) $("#bullet2").attr('checked', 'checked');
   else if (now == -460) $("#bullet3").attr('checked', 'checked');

    $(".imgContentSlideMask").animate({ SlideNext: now }, {
        step: function (val, fx) {
            $(".imgContentSlideMask").css('-webkit-transform', "translateY(" + val + "px)");
            $(".imgContentSlideMask").css('-moz-transform', "translateY(" + val + "px)");
        },
        duration: 700
    }, 'easeInElastic');
};

window.setInterval(function () {
    $("#TechSlider").timer();
}, 100000);
```

Content slider Interval calling to tech slider, and content slider not working..

How to call each function with respect to their intervals?

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite `jQuery.fn.timer`, so only the last value you assign it is retained.

First you assign to it for the content slider:

```
//Content Slider

$("#example p:first").css("display", "block");
jQuery.fn.timer = function () {
// Here --^
```

...then you *overwrite* it when doing the tech slider:

```
//Tech Slider

$("#TechSlider").css("display", "block");
jQuery.fn.timer = function() {
// Here --^
```

So naturally only the last value you assigned is kept, exactly like

```
a = 1;
a = 2;
```

...leaves `2` in `a`, overwriting the `1`.